# Python-docx add_picture size won't print as shown on screen

Tags: python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I have wrote a program for work that creates a report in MS Word using python-docx. I am adding pictures, which I size to my liking. Everything looks great...until I print. The pictures I added using python-docx have "un-sized" themselves. My document looks great on the screen and even in the print preview. This problem can also be seen if printing to PDF. Using the demo from python-docx, which exhibits the problem as well...

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()
document.add_picture('picture.jpg', width=Inches(4.9))
document.save('demo.docx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a related issue here in the `python-docx` issue list:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/94

If you'll add your symptoms there we'll see if we can get it fixed up.

Are you using actual Microsoft Word or are you using LibreOffice?

**UPDATE:**

This issue was remedied in the v0.8.2 release of python-docx on Feb 16 2015.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Word